# Can I use a Wi-Fi router as a LAN switch with a Starlink router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have just purchased a Starlink Connection. Love it, except that I didn't even consider that it might not have a single Ethernet port in the router; I just assumed it would. Can I utilisz a second Wi-Fi router with Ethernet ports to use as an Ethernet switch but instead of using the WAN for connection it uses it's Wi-Fi to link to the Starlink router?

It's not important that the speeds are as good over this connection as it's running a couple of minor utility devices that only have Ethernet ports. I know I can Bridge or NAT but not sure how my scenario will go with that. I have done it in the past but not well versed in the technical for this. Also I would like to not have the "Ethernet router" publicly broadcast, make it private to general user devices.

I did order SpaceX Starlink Ethernet adapter but it got damaged the first time I plugged it in and does not work. I contacted them and opened a ticket but they have not yet got back to me a week later. I assume eventually they will but for now I need to get connected to these devices.

Comment: https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-use-your-own-wi-fi-router-with-starlink

Answer (score 1):

Various "Wi-Fi extenders" very often have this as a built-in feature, but wireless routers rarely do (typically their firmware only lets you configure it as a Wi-Fi access point but not as a client). It works but it's not great.

One potential downside is that the extender or router in question needs to somehow deal with the restriction of one MAC address per associated client. Often this is done by performing MAC-level NAT on the fly, which works 90% of the time but there'll be situations that break it (e.g. some extenders don't handle IPv6 packets correctly).

Comment: Thanks you for that.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are looking for a way to "convert" WiFi to Ethernet - for example to connect devices without ethernet. In this case the feature your are looking for is usually called "**Client Mode**". If your router/AP is running [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/openwrt_as_clientdevice) you're good to go. For devices running vendor firmware you would have to check the WebUI/specs if they implemented this feature.

Comment: Thanks for that. I doubt my old main will do that. Not actually sure what the other runs. Will look into it. I might just take the startling adaptor apart so I can use it with my small switch.